# Error when use RequestQueue in Android?

Tags: android, web-services, android-volley, request-queueing

Here my code:

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
    try {
        params.put("email", email);
        params.put("pass", pass);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, "Link Create Account", params, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {               

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    queue.add(request);
```

"Link Create Account" is a link, it working fine with postman (Create only 1 account).

But sometime, I use this code in android, it create 2,3 account with the same details.

I don't know what happen! Any helps. Thank!

Comment: Meaning you call this multi times?

Comment: I use Log.w("Test",".."); It only print only 1 time.

Comment: maybe error is in your server side

Comment: My server is working fine with Postman and IOS client.

Comment: Pls add `request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));` right above `queue.add(request);`

Comment: :) I testing 5 times and it working fine, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agree with BNK, I have meet the same problem. The reason is for one request, server side spend more time than the client side can wait. For example your client will wait for 1 minutes then retry, but it takes 2 minutes for the server to finish the request, so your client will retry and there will be two result in server.

And there are two ways to solve the problem, one is to make the client wait for long enough time for the server to finish the request, or speed up your server side; another is like BNK said, make suer Volley will not retry.

Answer (score 3):

Volley uses RetryPolicy so update your code below

```
request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(20 * 1000, 1 , DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
queue.add(request);
```